# how to delete item from JSON object with angularjs

Tags: javascript, json

I want to delete the items which have `{"lat":0,"lng":0}` in this json object, here's the object :

```
[{
    "lat": 35.77118697154732,
    "lng": -5.809084439749561
}, {
    "lat": 35.77118697154732,
    "lng": -5.809084439749562
}, {
    "lat": 0,
    "lng": 0
}, {
    "lat": 0,
    "lng": 0
}, {
    "lat": 0,
    "lng": 0
}]
```

I tried this:

```
storyboard.deleteLngAndLatEqualZeo = function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var currentData = data[i];
        if (currentData.lat == 0 && currentData.lng == 0) {
            data.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

It doesn't work. Can someone help?

Comment: use `Array.prototype.filter` function

Comment: how to use it ??

Comment: Your code doesn't work because the `data.lenght` is beeing changed inside the loop by using `splice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control) function like this:

```js
var data = [{
    "lat": 35.77118697154732,
    "lng": -5.809084439749561
}, {
    "lat": 35.77118697154732,
    "lng": -5.809084439749562
}, {
    "lat": 0,
    "lng": 0
}, {
    "lat": 0,
    "lng": 0
}, {
    "lat": 0,
    "lng": 0
}];

var result = data.filter(function(d) {
  return !(d.lat === 0 && d.lng === 0);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `slice`, Checkout my answer

```
for (var i = data.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    var latData=data[i].lat;
    var lngData=data[i].lng;
    if (put condition) {
        data.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
data = 
[{
    "lat": 35.77118697154732,
    "lng": -5.809084439749561
}, {
    "lat": 35.77118697154732,
    "lng": -5.809084439749562
}, {
    "lat": 0,
    "lng": 0
}, {
    "lat": 0,
    "lng": 0
}, {
    "lat": 0,
    "lng": 0
}];

deleteLngAndLatEqualZeo = function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var currentData = data[i];
        if (currentData.lat == 0 && currentData.lng == 0) {
            data.splice(i, 1);
            --i;
        }
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}

deleteLngAndLatEqualZeo(data);
```